# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have got this JSON - address.json

```
{
  "province": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "province1",
      "district": [{
          "districtID": "1",
          "districtName": "district1"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "province2",
      "district": [{
          "districtID": "2",
          "districtName": "district2"
        }, {
          "districtID": "3",
          "districtName": "district3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

HTML Code

```
 <label for="addressProvince">State: </label>
 <select id="addressProvince"></select>
```

Javascript

```
//Province
$(function(){

    $.getJSON("address.json", function(data) {

        console.log( "success1");


        var provinceCount = data.province.length;
        var provinceList = '<option selected="selected" value="0">- select -</option>';

        for (var i = 0; i < provinceCount; i++) {
             provinceList += "<option value='" + data.province[i].id + "'>" + data.province[i].name + "</option>";
        }
        $("#addressProvince").html(provinceList);

    });
});

    //District  
    $('#addressProvince').on('change', function () {

    var provinceID = $(this).val();

    $.getJSON("address.json", function(data) {

        console.log( "success2");

        var provinceCount = data.province.length;

        for (i = 0; i < provinceCount; i++) {

                if(data.province[i].id == provinceID){

                    console.log("dis case 1 = "+ data.province[i].district.length); //***Problem case 1****

                    console.log("dis case 2 = "+ data[0].province[i].district.length); //***Problem case 2****

                    console.log("dis case 3 = "+ data[0].province[i].district[0].districtName); //***Problem case 3****
                }

        }

    });

});
//End District
```

How to get the length of district ?
My Console.log reporting an error

Case 1 Report :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Case 2 Report :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'province' of undefined

Case 3 Report :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'province' of undefined

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but are you sure the json file is loading? Like, if you do a `console.log(data)` as soon as you enter the callback, are you seeing anything?

Comment: `data.province[i].district` is undefined so `data` isn't what you have posted

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca if json file is loading `console.log( "success1");` is work

Comment: Have you tried using console.log(data.province[i] )?

Comment: @Snowmonkey [object Object]

Comment: what is the value for `i` when the error occurs? Hmm...

Comment: I've updated my example to use the data object as you did (with a for loop rather than the each() I'd used), simply removing the getJSON parts. As you can see, the first case causes no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First advice, work on one piece at a time. Remove the 'fetch stuff from the back-end' bit, and create a stub of working JSON that you can use for development. For example, use the JSON code you gave us, and create your object from that. Now, using that bit, write code that will iterate over your newly-created object. If you can get THAT piece working, it won't matter if the JSON comes from an inline variable, a statically passed variable set by PHP, or a getJSON call.

Next thing to note, why are you fetching the JSON all over again every time the user changes province options? You already have that information in your data, so fetching it again is wasted overhead. Use what you already have.

Third, while you can use a for loop, since you're using jQuery, use the $.each() to iterate over lists. IMHO, it works, and it seems a little more intuitive. All that said, try this code:

```js
var data = {
  "province": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "province1",
    "district": [{
      "districtID": "1",
      "districtName": "district1"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "province2",
    "district": [{
      "districtID": "2",
      "districtName": "district2"
    }, {
      "districtID": "3",
      "districtName": "district3"
    }]
  }]
};

//Province
$(function() {
  // create references to the various els in the DOM.
  var provincePane = $(".provinceSelector");
  var districtPane = $(".districtSelector");
  var addressProvinceEl = $("#addressProvince");
  var addressDistrictEl = $("#addressDistrict");
  // create a blank option, we'll use this as the default el.
  var defaultEl = $("<option>")
                      .prop("selected", true)
                      .val("0")
                      .text("- select -");
                      
  // Insert a copy of that default element into the province select.
  addressProvinceEl.append(defaultEl.clone());

  // Using jQuery's each function, we can loop over every data.province
  $.each(data.province, function(){
    // create an option el for this particular province.
    var optionEl = $("<option>")
                    .val(this.id)
                    .text(this.name);
    // append the option into the select.
    addressProvinceEl.append(optionEl);
  })

  //District  
  addressProvinceEl.on('change', function() {
    // get the value of the currently selected option
    var provID = parseInt(this.value);
    // remove all options but the default option from the district select el
    addressDistrictEl.empty();
    addressDistrictEl.append(defaultEl.clone() );

    // If the user has gone back to '- select -', hide the district pane
    if (provID == 0) {
      districtPane.hide();
    } else {
      // otherwise, display the district pane.
      districtPane.show();
    }
    
    // iterate over the province list, and find the one matching 
    //   the selected option.
    $.each(data.province, function(){
      if(this.id == provID) {
        // We found a match! Now, using the current province, iterate 
        //  over the district list.
        $.each(this.district, function(){
          // create a new option for each district, setting properties...
          var optionEl = $("<option>")
                          .val(this.districtID)
                          .text(this.districtName);
          // ... and append that new option into the district selector.
          addressDistrictEl.append(optionEl);
        })
      }
    })

  });

});
//End District
```

```css
.districtSelector {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="provinceSelector">
  <label for="addressProvince">State: </label>
  <select id="addressProvince"></select>
</div>
<div class="districtSelector">
  <label for="addressDistrict">District: </label>
  <select id="addressDistrict"></select>
</div>
```

All that said, I went back to YOUR code rather than my code above, simply removed the getJSON bits, saved the JSON object as a data variable, and ran your code as-is otherwise. I do get no error on the first data selector (`data.province[i].district.length`), but the other two do error out, as data (for example) is not an array -- it is an object. It is a root-level object, of which there is only one. At least, I think that's how it works. **[To see it working as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/ksgrL1xt/1/)**, or here's your code **without the getJSON() bits**.

```js
var data = {
  "province": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "province1",
    "district": [{
      "districtID": "1",
      "districtName": "district1"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "province2",
    "district": [{
      "districtID": "2",
      "districtName": "district2"
    }, {
      "districtID": "3",
      "districtName": "district3"
    }]
  }]
};

//Province
$(function() {
  console.log("success1");


  var provinceCount = data.province.length;
  var provinceList = '<option selected="selected" value="0">- select -</option>';

  for (var i = 0; i < provinceCount; i++) {
    provinceList += "<option value='" + data.province[i].id + "'>" + data.province[i].name + "</option>";
  }
  $("#addressProvince").html(provinceList);

  //District  
  $('#addressProvince').on('change', function() {

    var provinceID = $(this).val();
    console.log("success2");

    var provinceCount = data.province.length;

    for (i = 0; i < provinceCount; i++) {

      if (data.province[i].id == provinceID) {

        console.log("dis case 1 = " + data.province[i].district.length); //***Problem case 1****

        //console.log("dis case 2 = " + data[0].province[i].district.length); //***Problem case 2****

        //console.log("dis case 3 = " + data[0].province[i].district[0].districtName); //***Problem case 3****
      
      for (var j = 0; j < data.province[i].district.length; j++){
        var district = data.province[i].district[j];
        var optionEl = "<option value='"+district.districtID+"' >"+district.districtName+"</option>";
        $("#addressDistrict").append(optionEl);
      }
      }
    }

  });
});
//End District
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="provinceSelector">
  <label for="addressProvince">State: </label>
  <select id="addressProvince"></select>
</div>
<div class="districtSelector">
  <label for="addressDistrict">District: </label>
  <select id="addressDistrict"></select>
</div>
```